# live555 problem while streaming over the internet

Tags: c++, tcp, streaming, udp, media

I've compiled with VS the live555 source code, and it works just fine if I try to stream locally a file

e.g.

Command Line:
live555.exe myfile.mp3
VLC Connection String
rtsp://169.254.1.231:8554/myfile.mp3

but if I try to stream it over the internet, VLC communicates with live555, but live555 won't send data to him

Command Line
live555.exe myfile.mp3
VLC Connection String
rtsp://80.223.43.123:8554/myfile.mp3

I've already forwarded the 8554 port (both tcp/udp) and tried to disable my firewall but this doesn't solve.

How is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To troubleshoot:

- Are you streaming RTP over RTSP: have you checked the "Use RTP over RTSP (TCP)" option in VLC? You can check this in VLC under the preferences: input/codecs->Demuxers->RTP/RTSP. You can try to see if this solves the problem in which case it could be that UDP is blocked.
- You speak of forwarding. Do you mean port forwarding from one machine to the RTSP server? if so-> if you are not doing RTP over RTSP, then you would also need to forward the ports for the media which is not the same as the RTSP port (554 or 8554). These ports are exchanged during the RTSP SETUP. If you do RTP over RTSP the media is interleaved over 554 or 8554 and you don't have to worry about this.

Also, another good debugging tool is the live555 openRTSP application. You can run it from the command line and specify "-t" for RTP over RTSP, which is basically what the VLC option does. You can specify "-T" for HTTP tunneling, etc and it allows you to write captured media packets to file, etc.